# Единичная матрица не выводится

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, матрицы

Не могу понять почему не работает код. Должен печатать единичную матрицу.

```
#include <iostream>


class Matrix {
public:
    int columns;
    int rows;
    int **containment;

    void function_name_of_init_action(Matrix *matrix_pointer1) {
        matrix_pointer1->containment = (int **) malloc(matrix_pointer1->columns * sizeof(int *)); //add space for cols
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer1->columns; ++i) {
            matrix_pointer1->containment[i] = (int*) malloc(matrix_pointer1->rows * sizeof(int)); // add space for rows
        }
    }

    void fill_matrix(Matrix *matrix_pointer2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer2->columns; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_pointer2->rows; ++j) {
                if (i == j) {     // main diag
                    matrix_pointer2->containment[i][j] = 1;  // fill with const == 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void free_matrix(Matrix *matrix_pointer3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer3->columns; ++i) {
            free(matrix_pointer3->containment[i]);
        }
        free(matrix_pointer3->containment);
    }

    void print_matrix(Matrix *matrix_pointer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_pointer->columns; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_pointer->rows; ++j) {
                printf("%d ", matrix_pointer->containment[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix_variable_name = {10, 10};

    matrix_variable_name.function_name_of_init_action(&matrix_variable_name);
    matrix_variable_name.fill_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
    matrix_variable_name.free_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
    matrix_variable_name.print_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если брать *конкретно ваш код*, то проблемы две — вы не инициализируете не диагональные элементы, и освобождаете память, а потом выводите матрицу (после освобождения никто не гарантирует, что в памяти останется что-то, что там было).

Исправления:

```
if (i == j) {     // main diag
    matrix_pointer2->containment[i][j] = 1;  // fill with const == 1
}
else matrix_pointer2->containment[i][j] = 0;
```

и

```
matrix_variable_name.fill_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
matrix_variable_name.print_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
matrix_variable_name.free_matrix(&matrix_variable_name);
```

сделают код рабочим.

Но это все мелочи... Потому что главное — это неверный код в принципе. И дело даже не в том, что матрица располагается построчно, а у вас — постолбцово (но при этом выводится неверно — столбцы у вас располагаются как строки). Беда в том, что вы не поняли, зачем вообще классы. И вы передаете в функции указатель на объект матрицы, который передан уже и так! В результате получается "масло масляное".

Стоит убрать только эту неприятность, как код уже станет существенно проще и понятнее... Да, я сразу же уберу ваши чисто С-шные `malloc/free` и заменю их С++'ными `new/delete`, и поменяю местами строки и столбцы.

```
class Matrix {
public:
    int columns;
    int rows;
    int **containment;

    void function_name_of_init_action() {
        containment = new int*[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            containment[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    void fill_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                    containment[i][j] = (i==j);  // fill with const == 1
    }

    void free_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            delete[] containment[i];
        delete[]containment;
    }

    void print_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                printf("%d ", containment[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix_variable_name = {10, 10};

    matrix_variable_name.function_name_of_init_action();
    matrix_variable_name.fill_matrix();
    matrix_variable_name.print_matrix();
    matrix_variable_name.free_matrix();
}
```

Согласитесь, уже красивее?

Но это не все. После создания матрицы

```
Matrix matrix_variable_name = {10, 10};
```

ее надо обязательно инициализировать, так как в этот момент `containment` указывает в никуда! Работать с такой матрицей нельзя. Так что имеет смысл инициализировать ее сразу же — в конструкторе.

Как и освобождать — в деструкторе (вы уже получили неприятности с освобождением матрицы не-вовремя). Не будем даже ничего особо переписывать, просто будем вызывать функции где нужно.

Заодно исправим полную открытость вашего класса, спрятав то, к чему не стоит пускать посторонних.

И вот теперь этот код уже становится похожим на нормальный С++:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int columns;
    int rows;
    int **containment;

    void free_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            delete[] containment[i];
        delete[]containment;
    }

    void function_name_of_init_action() {
        containment = new int*[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            containment[i] = new int[columns];
    }

public:

    Matrix(int r, int c):rows(r),columns(c)
    {
        function_name_of_init_action();
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        free_matrix();
    }


    void fill_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                    containment[i][j] = (i==j);  // fill with const == 1
    }


    void print_matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                printf("%d ", containment[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix_variable_name = {10, 10};
    matrix_variable_name.fill_matrix();
    matrix_variable_name.print_matrix();
}
```

Comment: Господи спасибо Вам большое